# Hive: Join Performance - String vs Int

Tags: hive

A Hive query that joins table runs 12+ hours.

This query joins string columns. So for each column, hive has to do a string compare. It would be logical to join on strings.

Does it make sense to convert string columns to int? Or is the impact in general considered as too low?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to improve the join performance by adding some properties in hive query that will join better.

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=false;
```

I have seen the above parameters make a difference many times. Maybe if you give us more information as to how many tables are u joining and how big are they. There will be better solution.

Comment: I disagree, "hive.auto.convert.join" is to enable map join which is a nice feature in Hive. When one table is small enough, hive loads the whole table in memory and scan through the other table and as a result the join operation is performed much faster. Whether or not map join is going to improve your query heavily depends on you data and tables size, but I don't think simply disabling a good feature of hive is a smart suggestion for performance improvement. This is a good read on different types of joins in hive, http://www.openkb.info/2014/11/understanding-hive-joins-in-explain.html